# Как создать список данных терминальной командой whois?

Tags: linux, terminal, whois

Добрый день!Как написать скрипт, который используя команду whois в терминале создаст список данных. Например :

Есть некий файл **'file'**
в теле файла находится список доменов 
например 
ulmart_ru,
citilink_ru,
shop_ru,
 и тд....

мне нужно выгрудить в файл об этих доменах используя команду  whois

**startscript.sh**

SHELL=/bin/bash
idsite=/script/file

whois idsite# > var/log/name_whois.log

в файле нужно чтобы были все данные о домене, все которые показывает

**name_whois.log**

"Domain Name: ENOM_COM 
   Registrar: ENOM, INC. 
   Sponsoring Registrar IANA ID: 48 
    Whois Server: whois_enom_com 
   Referral URL: _enom_com 
    Name Server: NS1_ENOM_COM 
   .....

domain:       CITILINK_RU 
nserver:      ns1_merlion_ru 
nserver:      ns2_merlion_ru 
state:        REGISTERED, DELEGATED 
admin-contact:nic_ru/ 
org:          Merlion Group Limited 
registrar:    RU-CENTER-RU 
created:      1997.09.25 
..... и тд

Answer (score 0):

Вот так что ли надо? Я не совсем понял.

list-hosts:

```
example.ru
example.com
example.net
example.org
example.biz
```

startscript.sh:

```
for i in $(< list-hosts)
    do
    whois "$i" | egrep -i '(nserver|domain)' >> /var/log/name_whois.log
done
```

Comment: да примено так ) спасибо сейчас папробую

Comment: а как можно выборку сделать  в этом лог фале (name_whois.log) только по Name Server: и Domain Name: ?

Comment: @airat, обновил ответ.

Comment: Трудно быть Богом, Дон Румата)? я бы поиграл с tee -а,  вместо редирекции >>, сразу можно поглядеть вывод и иметь файл на будущее.

Comment: @Hellseher, да. Именно, у меня даже цитата в профиле оттуда. По поводу `tee` - постоянно про него забываю, хоть и знаю.